# In Visual Studio, is there a keyboard shortcut to show the DataTip (that floating watch that appears on mouseover) in code editor window?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, DataTip is the floating watch that appears when you hover your mouse over a variable and it shows its value:

[image: datatip appearing when mouseover variable]

Is there a way to do it from the keyboard instead of the mouse?

**PS.:** I now about the QuickWatch window (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>). I want a quicker watch than that. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is `Edit.QuickInfo`command which by default is set to `CTRL+K, CTRL+I`

Answer (score 1):

I am using a visual studio extension (RevDeBug) to achieve the desired result.
It has an option to display the value over the variables.
You can find it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RevDeBug.RecordReplayforNET-RevDeBug)
[image: How it works]